# Use OAuthWebSecurity With MVC 3.0 with custom membership provider

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, dotnetopenauth, membership-provider

I am looking for how can I implement OAuthWebSecurity with Mvc 3
I have a custom membership provider and I would like to add Facebook, Google and Twitter authentication to my website.

Authentication scenario using Facebook for example

1- the user chooses login using Facebook.
2- check Facebook authentication
3- if success --> check if the user exist in my database
4- if exist --> make the user logged in, if not create a new user in my custom user table

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please See Below Link It Give you Fully Information about it

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Comment: This appears to be a dead link. I think this is the working version http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample / template project which implements a custom membership provider based on the Entity Framework, it has custom DB schema, external login / signup functionality via Google, Twitter, Facebook...

https://github.com/kriasoft/site-sdk